# problems with wildcards in scripts

Tags: bash

I am having this "problem" with wildcards and I just cant figure out why it is like that.

following example:

```
#!/bin/bash
basefolder=/tmp/
rm $basefolder"processed/*.txt*"
```

this leads to an error message "cant find /tmp/processed/*.txt*" for rm.
this is of course not correct, because there are files in this folder and when i just copy and past the folder from the error message it deletes it correctly.

same applies for for loops

```
#!/bin/bash
basefolder=/tmp/
for file in $basefolder"processed/*.txt*"
...
```

will not work, my workaround is the following

```
#!/bin/bash
basefolder=/tmp/
filepattern=$basefolder"processed/*.txt*"
for file in $filepattern
...
```

another way would be to set the basefolder just /tmp and then use $basefolder/processed/*.txt* (that would work), but i am more curious why this problem even exists.

can anyone give me an explanation?

Comment: What about doing `for file in ${basefolder}processed/*.txt*` ?

Comment: Indeed, the purpose of quoting in the shell is to prevent wildcard expansion and other metacharacter processing. Don't use quotes if you want the wildcards expanded.

Comment: wildcard expansion happens even with a wildcard in quotes. The difference is that Quote Removal happens only after all expansions as the last step

Comment: @jkbkot No, it doesn't. Something like `foo="*.txt"` stores a literal asterisk in the parameter `foo`; the wildcard expansion only occurs when you *expand* the parameter: `echo $foo` produces a list of text files in the current directory; `echo "$foo"` produces the literal string '*.txt'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is about *quoting*:

```
ls /tmp/"foo*"
```

means *list the file called exactly `/tmp/foo*`* It will **not** match `/tmp/foobar` or `/tmp/foo`

`ls /tmp/foo*` (no quotes) matches both `/tmp/foo` and `/tmp/foobar`

So, these should all work:

```
basefolder=/tmp/
rm ${basefolder}processed/*.txt*

# I like this better, no need for ${}:
basefolder=/tmp
rm $basefolder/processed/*.txt*

# the loop:
basefolder=/tmp
for file in $basefolder/processed/*.txt*
```

Comment: Nice; while not needed in this specific case, it's generally safer to double-quote variable references and literal path components; in this case: `"$basefolder/processed/"*.txt*` (note that the shell allows you to mix quoted and unquoted portions in a single string).

Answer (score 0):

Without protecting the pattern `*.txt*` it works.
Therefore the script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
basefolder=/tmp
/bin/rm "$basefolder"/processed/*.txt*
```